# Include Dotnet runtime in Visual Studio App

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've made an app using visual studio running on .NET 5.0 but if the app is executed from a computer that doesn't have it installed it will show a popup asking to install .NET
Is it possible the app and include a .NET installation with so it can run on any PC without any additional installation ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained That's being called self-contained deployment since .NET Core 1.0.

Comment: I see, and is it possible to only include the required files, because If I have a basic window with some text in it and include the dotnet runtime it will be 130Mb